# Após clicar em algum item do ListActivity, sempre o primeiro registro é carregado

Tags: android

Bom pessoal, 
estou com um problema ao carregar um registro a partir de um `ListActivity`.

Quando clico em algum item do `ListActivity`, minha aplicação deve abrir a tela de cadastro para que eu edite algum dado. 
Até aqui, tudo bem.. o problema é que sempre carrega o primeiro item do `ListActivity`. Não importa se a existem 100 itens, após clicar em qualquer um, sempre o primeiro é carregado.

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia do que está sendo feito errado (ou não está sendo feito) e puder ajudar ai..

Caso seja necessário algum outra informação ou código, só dizer.

Muito Obrigado!

//Arquivo ConsCliente.java

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);

    TextView tvCliente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCodigo);
    TextView tvNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeLinha);
    TextView tvCnpj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCNPJLinha);
    TextView tvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);

    Intent it = new Intent(this, CadCliente.class);  
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    String codigoCli = tvCliente.getText().toString();
    String nomeCli = tvNome.getText().toString();
    String cnpjCli = tvCnpj.getText().toString();
    String emailCli = tvEmail.getText().toString();


    params.putString("codigoCli", codigoCli);
    params.putString("nomeCli", nomeCli);
    params.putString("cnpjCli", cnpjCli);
    params.putString("emailClie", emailCli);


    it.putExtras(params);
    startActivity(it);

}
```

//Aquivo CadCliente.java

```
public class CadCliente extends Activity{
EditText etNome;
EditText etEmail;
EditText etCodigo;
EditText etCNPJ;

ClienteDAO clienteDAO;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cadcliente);
    clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO(this);

    etCodigo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCodCliente);
    etNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRazaoNome);
    etTelefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTelefone);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etCNPJ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCpfCnpj);

    //Testes
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle params = intent.getExtras();  

    if(params!=null)
    {   
     String mostraCodigo = params.getString("codigoCli");
     String mostraNome = params.getString("nomeCli");
     String mostraCNPJ = params.getString("cnpjCli");
     String mostraEmail = params.getString("emailCli");

     etCodigo.setText(mostraCodigo);
     etNome.setText(mostraNome);
     etCNPJ.setText(mostraCNPJ);
     etEmail.setText(mostraEmail);
    }

    //fimTestes

    Button btCancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCancelarCadCli);
    btCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });


    Button btSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSalvarCadCli);
    btSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Variáveis
            String codigo = "";
            String nome = "";
            String email = "";
            String cnpj = "";

            codigo = etCodigo.getText().toString();
            nome = etNome.getText().toString();
            email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            cnpj = etCNPJ.getText().toString();

            //Cria o cliente
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

            //Abre a conexão com o banco de dados
            clienteDAO.open();

            //Salva o cliente
            //clienteDAO.novoCliente(cliente);
            clienteDAO.atualizarCliente(cliente);

            //Fecha a conexão com o banco de dados
            clienteDAO.close();

            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

//Arquivo ClienteAdapter.

```
package br.sysandroid.dao;

import java.util.List; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.sysandroid.R.id;
import br.sysandroid.R.layout;
import br.sysandroid.model.Cliente;

public class ClienteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

private List<Cliente> clientes;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ClienteAdapter(Context context, List<Cliente> clientes) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.clientes = clientes;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    try {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        trace("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void trace(String msg) {
    toast(msg);
}

public void toast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public int getCount() {
    return clientes.size();
}

public void remove(final Cliente cliente) {
    this.clientes.remove(cliente);
}

public void add(final Cliente clientes) {
    this.clientes.add((Cliente) clientes);
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return clientes.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvCodigo;
    public TextView tvNome;
    public TextView tvTelefone;
    public TextView tvEmail;
    public TextView tvCNPJ;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    try {

        Cliente cliente = clientes.get(position);

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout.linha_cliente, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvCodigo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvCodigo);
            holder.tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvNomeLinha);
            holder.tvEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvEmail);
            holder.tvCNPJ = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvCNPJLinha);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvCodigo.setText(String.valueOf(cliente.getId()));
        holder.tvNome.setText(cliente.getNome());
        holder.tvEmail.setText(cliente.getEmail());
        holder.tvCNPJ.setText(cliente.getCnpj());


        return convertView;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        trace("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Cadê o adapter?

Comment: @IgorRonner - Adicionado. Obrigado!

Comment: @emauelsm vocês está usando uma ListActivity?

Comment: @Luídne - É isso mesmo. Não sei onde estava com a cabeça pra escrever ListView. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A razão de pegar sempre o primeiro item está relacionada como você está recuperando esse item selecionado.

Ao invés de obter o item pelo valor da `View` pegue o item selecionado diretamente do seu `Adapter`. Como a seguir:

```
Cliente cliente = (Cliente) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

Intent it = new Intent(this, CadCliente.class);  
Bundle params = new Bundle();

// os param.putString com o cliente
```

Isso vai até resumir o seu código.

Comment: Consegui aki. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Talvez fazendo o findViewById na View que foi clicada funcione:

```
TextView tvCliente = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCodigo);
TextView tvNome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeLinha);
TextView tvCnpj = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCNPJLinha);
TextView tvEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
```